# Laravel - check request method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm an iOS lead on an app and trying to fix some API bugs whilst our dev is 'unavailable'. I'm almost completely new to Laravel and trying to check what the request method is. I have followed some guidance from another question but have been unable to get it working:

```
public function defaults(Request $request, User $user){
    $follow_ids = explode(',', env('FOLLOW_DEFAULTS'));

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        return ['user' => $user];
    }

    $user->follows()->syncWithoutDetaching($follow_ids);

    return ['user.follows' => $user->follows->toArray()];
}
```

Do you know where I might be going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

When the request is returned it always just seems to skip over and return `['user.follows' => $user->follows->toArray()]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$request` should be an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`. This class extends Symfony's request (`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`), which is actually where the `isMethod()` method is defined.

Basically, given the function definition as posted, it reads "if this is a `POST` request, just return the user data. if this is not a `POST` request (e.g. `GET`), update and return the relationship data."

So, if you send a `POST` request, you'll get the `['user' => $user]` response. If you send any other request method (e.g. `GET`), you'll modify the `follows` relationship and get the `['user.follows' => $user->follows->toArray()]` response.

To me, this seems backwards. I would think you'd want the `POST` request to update the data, and any other request (e.g. `GET`) to just return data.

If this is correct, you need to negate your `isMethod` check:

```
if (! $request->isMethod('post')) {
    return ['user' => $user];
}
```

More appropriately you should define separate controller actions to handle `POST` vs `GET` requests, but that is outside the scope of this question, and probably more than you want to get into as a temporary maintainer.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the request is not a POST so the `if` check is never true. You could echo the method name like this:

```
$method = $request->method();

echo $method; 

// or var_dump($method);
```